# MailSo echo folder contents

Tags: php, email, sendmail, phalcon

Im currently messing around with PHP, Fairly new to it.

Im using the MailSo library to connect to my mail server. The goal is get the contents from the INBOX folder and display them in a table.

At the moment all im trying to do is just echo or `print_r()` the entire INBOX folder. I had it working yesturday but did not touch the project since then and forgot what i did.

Here is my code

```
include 'lib/MailSo/MailSo.php';

echo '<pre>';

$oLogger = \MailSo\Log\Logger::SingletonInstance()
->Add(\MailSo\Log\Drivers\Inline::NewInstance("\r\n", true));
$oData = null;
try {
    $oMailClient = \MailSo\Mail\MailClient::NewInstance()->SetLogger($oLogger);

    $oData = $oMailClient
        ->Connect('xxxxx.web-hosting.com', 993, \MailSo\Net\Enumerations\ConnectionSecurityType::SSL)
        ->Login('xxxx@xxxx.com', 'mypass')
        ->MessageList('INBOX');

    echo $oData->FolderName('INBOX');

    $oMailClient->LogoutAndDisconnect();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

The problem lies somewhere here: `echo $oData->FolderName('INBOX');`

Its quite confusing since MailSo do not have any documentation for there code.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Like do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on?

Comment: Yes im getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method MailSo\Mail\MessageCollection::FolderName() in ....

Comment: I am familiar with this library, however this is saying that `FolderName()` is not a function of the class you are assigning it. See if `$oMailClient->FolderName('INBOX');` works.

Comment: @Rasclatt echo returns a string error , but print_r returns a huge array.

Comment: print_r($oMailClient->MessageList('INBOX'));

Comment: I downloaded that library and there doesn't seem to be a function called `FolderName`, just a variable `$this->FolderName `. There are other folder methods though like `FolderList()`.

Comment: Would you know how to list only the emails in the inbox folder

Comment: No, sorry. I don't really know anything about this library.

Comment: Would you by any chance know of another mail library which actually has documentation :P